# Unable to run StarCraft through Wine (stable 4.0; Mint 19, Intel iGPU)

Tags: wine, games

I'm having exactly the same problem as [the most recent tester on WineHQ's AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35171&iTestingId=106007&bShowAll=true). That is, StarCraft.exe consumes one core of my CPU and nothing happens. I've saved a complete log of terminal output [here](https://pastebin.com/gu5cQ5jU).

Unlike that tester,  who was able to run the game with wine-staging 4.8, when I try with winehq-staging 4.12 even the Battle.net launcher doesn't work properly (this was the subject of [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529664/graphics-problems-running-battle-net-issues-with-vulkan-mint-18-igpu)). That seemed to have something to do with Vulkan; the launcher does work with stable 4.0, but I still get the following errors when running vulkaninfo:

```
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Answer (score 0):

After *much* trial and error, I've got it to work by downgrading Wine all the way back to version 3(.21-staging). This has doubtless broken something else, so I'm leaving the question open. This feels more like a hack than a fix.