# 64-bit version of application crashing with Wine

Tags: wine, 64bit, games

*Disclaimer: I'm a Linux newbie and know nothing about computers. Sorry if anything below is obvious or stupid.*

I'm running Mint 19 (64-bit) with winehq-staging=3.21.0~bionic (version 4 [seems to cause bugs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532188/unable-to-run-starcraft-through-wine-stable-4-0-mint-19-intel-igpu) with the applications I want to run).

Over the last couple of months I've been playing Starcraft, which launches through Blizzard's Battle.net application, with no problems since downgrading Wine to 3.21. As of yesterday I found that the game crashed on reaching the initial loading screen (before menu options are available). The launcher still runs fine, so I used it to check for updates and scan for missing or corrupt files - nothing. I reinstalled the game, then Wine, and rebooted, with no effect. Then I thought to look at the "game settings" in the launcher, tried starting the game in 32-bit mode, and it worked.

---

There have been no updates or patches in over a week. Just to be sure though, I again checked for updates and scanned for missing or corrupt files. The latter returned nothing, but the check for updates now ran indefinitely without, as far as I can see, sending or receiving any significant amount of data. The launcher still responds to other inputs. I checked my Internet connection, and it's fine. Anyway, the game itself does not require an Internet connection to run.

The launcher can be run from three different executables, and I remembered at least one of them was mentioned as a possible source of problems back when I was trying to get things to work with Wine 4. So, to be thorough, I've tried all three. It seems that the update issue only happens when I launch using StarCraft Launcher.exe, though the failure of the 64-bit game client and success of the 32-bit one are consistent regardless of how I start the launcher. I have also had one or two cases where an error window has appeared from the launcher itself, but haven't been able to replicate this.

---

The errors I've got have not been 100% consistent, but here are the main ones I've seen (full logs linked below). Confusingly, all of them have sometimes appeared even when everything seemed to work, and none of them have always appeared when things didn't work (except for the first one, which appeared every time regardless) which suggests they might not be part of the problem...

```
003c:err:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx apartment not initialised
00e4:err:secur32:schan_free_handle Handle 0(0x15d0b0) is not of type 0x1
00e4:err:secur32:schan_free_handle Handle 1(0x15d0b8) is not of type 0x1
0019:err:winsock:WSAIoctl -> SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE request failed with status 0x2733
[1005/201735.676:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(157)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
[1005/201741.085:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1031)] Lost UI shared context.
[1005/184835.251:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(111)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Shared memory region is not valid
```

Here are the logs.

Opening launcher then running 32-bit game client (succeeds):

- [StarCraft Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/ev9y7wZi)
- [Battle.net Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/CNpSTPLx)
- [Battle.net.exe](https://pastebin.com/Qa2R47Dm)

Opening launcher then running 64-bit game client (game crashes, launcher still runs):

- [StarCraft Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/MLJYRhtt)
- [Battle.net Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/tg7cnHFS)
- [Battle.net.exe](https://pastebin.com/nMH9EL99)

Opening launcher then checking for updates:

- [StarCraft Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/H8A6FGvY) (continues indefinitely, but launcher still responds to other inputs)
- [Battle.net Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/PMkkRUmC) (succeeds)
- [Battle.net.exe](https://pastebin.com/ntAzFegh) (succeeds)

Just opening launcher:

- [StarCraft Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/gSiKaYyU)
- [Battle.net Launcher.exe](https://pastebin.com/MMcedD71)
- [Battle.net.exe](https://pastebin.com/hnG36EYn)

Comment: *in 32-bit mode, and it worked*  Not the first time porting something to 64 bits exposed buggy, incorrect code.  No, a pointer is not just another form of `int`, `size_t` is not `unsigned long`, and when you move to 64 bits implicit function declarations will break calls that return pointers.  There are a host of problem habits from bad programmers that can appear when a 32-bit executable is ported to 64 bits, so your experience is hardly unique. If you can get core files and/or stack traces, that can help. Also, a clean compile with **all** warnings and errors enabled.

Comment: What's weird though is that it worked fine until yesterday. In addition to the application not having been updated in over a week, I've just looked at dpkg.log and nothing seems to have changed between the last successful launch and the first unsuccessful one. I'll look into the other things you mentioned, thanks.

Comment: (As for a "clean compile", the game is downloaded and installed through the launcher, which is installed from an executable downloaded from the Blizzard website.)

Comment: Wine has forums where such a post would be far more on topic. U&L is not that much concerned about the *whys* of Windows binaries not running.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try there, but not too hopeful given evidence (including on the Wine site itself) that version 4 fails to run this application at all.